# Ps vita keeps blinking on and off

Tags: ps-vita

Hey can anyone help I had ps vita I replaced the screen with a new one it was working fine until I saw the blue light keeps blinking and playstation sign as well I tried to restart but it goes black doing the same thing has any  have ideals how to solve this problem?